# How to make a file with my own functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function

When I worked in Delphi, I had a special file with functions which were created by me. This file had a static way which was added to `library path` in Delphi settings and it could be used from anywere just by adding "lib" into "`uses`" block of `.pas` file.

Now I'm working in Swift and would like to make the same. I want to have a file which will have it's static way on PC and will be able to use itself from any `ViewController` just by adding "`Import myLib`"

How can I do it correctly?

Comment: You need to compile it into either a static library or a Framework, then add the resulting package to /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution without an explicit static library:

Create a Swift file somewhere outside any product folder containing a class (or multiple classes) and class functions, for example

```
class GlobalFunctions {

  class func function1()
  {
    println("function 1")
  }

  class func function2()
  {
    println("function 2")
  }
}
```

In each project you need the file add the file (<kbd>⌘⌥A</kbd>)to the project but uncheck `Copy items if needed` in the dialog box.

Call a function with

```
GlobalFunctions.function1()
```

Any import statement or changing Build Settings is not needed